# create single html table using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: expected table in this format]

this script generates 4 jquery ui tabs with 4 html tables inside it,

how do i combine these tables to make it in a single table, attached a screenshot of final table.

```
var data = $.parseJSON("{\"version\":\"5.2\",\"user_type\":\"online\",\"user\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":51},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":57},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":98}]}");

const setTables = new Set();
$.each(data.user, function(key, value) {
let table;
var row = $("<tr/>");

if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length)
    table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
else
    table = $('<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered"></table>');
    table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);

row.append($("<td/>").text(value.name));
row.append($("<td/>").text(value.id));

table.append(row);

if(!setTables.has(value.id)) {
    table.append( $("<thead><tr><th>NAME</th><th>ID</th></tr></thead>") );
    setTables.add(value.id);
    $( "#ul-tabs" ).append("<li><a href=\"#tabs-"+ value.id +"\">"+value.name+"</a></li>");
    $( "#tabs" ).append("<div id=\"tabs-"+value.id+"\">"+table.prop('outerHTML')+"</div>");
}
});

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

[View fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d19918/nz1yc3x0/8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactor your code to achieve this.

```js
var data = $.parseJSON("{\"version\":\"5.2\",\"user_type\":\"online\",\"user\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":51},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":57},{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":98},{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"id\":45},{\"name\":\"XYZ\",\"id\":98}]}");

let names = data.user.map(i => i.name)
  .filter((el, i, a) => a.indexOf(el) == i);
  
function idsForName(name, array) {
 return array.filter(el => el.name === name).map(el => el.id);
}

let $table = $('<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered"></table>');

$table.attr('id', 'main_table');

let $thead = $("<thead/>");
let $tbody = $("<tbody/>");
let $hRow = $("<tr/>").addClass('head-row');

if(names.length) $hRow.append($("<th/>").text('NAME'));

names.forEach(el => {
 let $row = $("<tr/>");
  $row.append($("<td/>").text(el));
  let ids = idsForName(el, data.user);
  ids.forEach((id, index) => {
   let th = '.th-' + index;
  if(!$hRow.find(th).length) $hRow.append($("<th/>").addClass('th-' + index).text('ID'));
  $row.append($("<td/>").text(id));
 });
 $tbody.append($row);
});
$thead.append($hRow);

$table.append($thead).append($tbody);
$('#tabs').append($table.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```css
body{
    margin: 20px;
  }
  th {
    text-align: center;
  }
  td {
    text-align: center;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: separate;
  }
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
  div#export_excel {
      float: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 4px;
  }
  button#btnExport {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 100; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">

</div>
```

Comment: what if want to add another row after john,
say 2nd row has name as XYZ, and ID as 1, 50, 45, 98